# Gnu Parallel and --link argument

Tags: linux, bash, gnu, gnu-parallel

Hi i'm very new to linux and learning to use the terminal and bash. currently i'm running through the GNU Parallel Tutorial. I've come to the section that talks about linking arguments with the --link :::+

if i try using link the terminal says unknown option and if i try using :::+ it will say no such file or directory.

i'm i on the wrong version of GNU Parallel as the tutorial on the web is for 20160822 where as the tutorial if i use man parallel_tutorial it says 20140622.

i've tried to update my parallel version but I cant seem to get this link option to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the tutorial that comes with the version of GNU Parallel you use (`man parallel_tutorial`).

The reason is that the tutorial online is made for the newest version.

In 20160822 --xapply was renamed to --link, 20160422 introduced :::+.

`parallel --version` will give you which version you run.